# How to programmatically reference a Silverlight DataGrid cell?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

Most grids use a syntax such as MyGrid[row, col] to reference a particular cell programatically.

How is this done, say, in C#, for the Silverlight DataGrid?  All examples I've
seen thus far use only XAML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If binding the itemssource to an observablecollection, you can get at the rows and volume by modifying that collection.  The ui propogates the change automatically

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You could use a simple grid. And have reference to any grid cell by using Grid.SetColumn and Grid.SetRow Methods.

See links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setcolumn.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setrow.aspx

Short and quick example:

XAML:

`<Grid Height="Auto" Name="Mygrid" Width="Auto" />`

c#:

```
string[] _names = new string[] { "first", "second", "three" };

        Mygrid.ShowGridLines = true;

        Mygrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
        Mygrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

        int rows = 3;
        int cols = 3;
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            Mygrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            Mygrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        for (int c = 0; c < Mygrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; c++)
        {
            int rowIndex = 0;
            foreach (string s in _names)
            {
                var someControll = new TextBox();
                someControll.Text = string.Format("{0} row in {1} column", s,c);
                someControll.Height = 25;

                Mygrid.Children.Add(someControll);

                Grid.SetRow(someControll, rowIndex);
                Grid.SetColumn(someControll, c);

                rowIndex += 1;
            }
        }
```